# Change material of faces of object with modifiers non-destructively?

Tags: materials, modifiers

So I have a sample object like this. I want to make the blue-colored red parts into new material.
I'd want to do it non-destructively so I'd want to keep my modifiers. Is it possible?

[.Blend file here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/mtugsx)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a color stripe directly into your material.

1. Use *Gradient texture* and ColorRamp as a mask
2. Add the *Mapping node* to control position of the stripe
3. Use *mix node* to combine different shaders

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting. Both of these do work on single color materials but I maybe simplified the sample file too much. I'd need a solution that works materials that use textures. Ideally something that works with uvmapped object.

Comment: Hello :). Textures and UV maps work just fine with this setup. Need some help?

Comment: I got it working, thanks. I'll mark your answer. Would you have ideas how to make this work for non-straight edges?

Comment: Also is there a way to make this work with two materials instead of having to combined two materials into one?

Comment: Please post this as anew question with examples :). Non-straight edges shouldn't pose a problem. Using two materials is possible through nodegroups.